# Function to write multiple Excel files with multiple sheets based on data frame variables

Tags: r, function, tidyverse, openxlsx

Teaching myself functions, and trying to implement here but stuck.

Here is a simplistic example of what I am trying to do.

I have a list of 2 tibbles.  Each is a different type of output, but each also has an "Agency" column.  I want to generate an Excel workbook for each Agency, and each workbook should have two sheets.  Each sheet will only contain the data for that Agency from the two tibbles.

```
rm(list = ls())

library(openxlsx)

Agency <- c("Agency1", "Agency2", "Agency3", "Agency3")
Value1.1 <- c(1, 4, 4, 5)
Value1.2 <- c(22,44,11,22)

Numbers <- tibble(Agency, Value1.1, Value1.2)

Value2.1 <- c("abc", "sif", "hwr", "yyd")
Value2.2 <- c("as", "is", "on", "for")

Letters <- tibble(Agency, Value2.1, Value2.2)

agency_name <- split(Numbers, str_sub(Numbers$Agency, 1, 30))

sheet_name = list("Numbers", "Letters")

lapply(seq_along(agency_name), 
       function(x) {
         openxlsx::write.xlsx(
           sheet_name,
           file = paste0("output/test/", names(Agency[x]), '.xlsx'),
           row.names = FALSE
         )
       })
```

Agency1.xlsx file would look like this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Naive approach with a loop

```
for (i in unique(Agency)) {
    data_sheets <- list("Numbers"= Numbers[Numbers$Agency==i,], "Letters"= Letters[Letters$Agency==i,])
    write.xlsx(data_sheets, file= paste0(i, '.xlsx'))
    }
```

With `lapply` :

```
lapply(seq_along(agency_name), 
       function(x) {
           write.xlsx(
           list("Numbers"= Numbers[Numbers$Agency==paste0("Agency",x),], "Letters"= Letters[Letters$Agency==paste0("Agency",x),]),
           file = paste0("Agency",x, '.xlsx'),
           row.names = FALSE
         )
       })
```

Comment: Thank you.  When I apply to my actual data I get an error that the function needs a simple vector, not a matrix.  But, in your example and my actual both are data frames - so I'm not clear why.  "Error: Must subset rows with a valid subscript vector.
x Subscript `direct_biz_options$Agency == i` must be a simple vector, not a matrix."

Comment: Can you  share the code you're trying to run please ? A `dput()` of your actual data might also be useful (if the data are confidential just input some random values).